# Clean Storage Cache Programmatically

Tags: magento-1.8, cache

How can storage cache be cleaned programaticaly, I have found an answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028159/magento-flush-cache-storage][1]
but this solution does not work.After I run it get this type of error 
(Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in ..\file.php on line 6).

Is there any other solution for flushing storage cache

Answer (score 3):

Create a file called flush.php with the following content:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
?>
```

and save it in your Magento root folder. Then run it any way you want, from the browser with http://yoursite.org/flush.php, with a cron or via CLI.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use below code for flush cache storage

```
define('MAGENTOROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

require_once(MAGENTOROOT.'/app/Mage.php');

Mage::app()->cleanCache();

flush();
```

OR

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
```